# Substitue values in jq from a txt file

Tags: bash, sed, jq, substitution

I'm executing `jq` like this:

```
jq '.backups[] | select(.resource_name == "resource_name") | {BackupTime: .updated_at, DiskName: .resource_name}' js.json | head -4
```

Is there a way to substitute the `.resource_name` field with the strings in a text file and execute a `jq` for each line of substitution from the text file?

For example, I have `list.txt` file with the below contents:

```
apple
mango
grapes
```

I want the `jq` command to be substituted as below:

```
jq '.backups[] | select(.resource_name == "**apple**") | {BackupTime: .updated_at, DiskName: .resource_name}' js.json | head -4
```

Comment: Show us the contents of the file and the desired output

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU paste and sed or parallel):

```
cat <<\! >command.txt
jq '.backups[] | select(.resource_name == "resource_name") | {BackupTime: .updated_at, DiskName: .resource_name}' js.json
!

cat <<\! >list.txt
apple
mango
grape
!

sed -n 'r command.tx' list.txt | paste - list.txt | sed -E 's/".*"(.*)\t(.*)/"**\2**"\1/e'
```

Put the jq  command in a text file

Put the list in a text file.

Apply the piped sed/paste/sed invocations.

The first sed invocation, creates a file of commands the length of the list.

The invocation of paste, appends the list separated by a tab.

The second invocation of sed, uses pattern matching to substitute then evalute the resulting line.

Another solution would to be to use GNU parallel:

```
parallel -k jq '.backups[] | select(.resource_name == "**{}**") | {BackupTime: .updated_at, DiskName: .resource_name}' js.json :::: list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
while read -r resource; do
    jq --arg resource "$resource" '.backups[] |
        select(.resource_name == $rname) |
        {BackupTime: .updated_at, DiskName: .resource_name}' js.json |
    head -4
done <list.txt
```